# Ionic Cordova can not share video on social sites

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the cordova social sharing plugin for sharing video on social sites. So far what I have achieved is, I have successfully captured video using following code -

```
var options = {
                limit: 1,
                duration: 15
            };

$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function (videoData) {
                $scope.videoUrl = videoData[0].fullPath;
            }, function (err) {
                // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
                //alert("video error : "+err);
            });
```

I can successfully find the captured video files url but unfortunately I can not share them to the social media sites. I have tried both of the following methods -

```
$cordovaSocialSharing
.share(message, subject, file, link)
```

and

```
$cordovaSocialSharing
.shareViaTwitter(message, image, link)
```

Now my question is -

1. Is there any way to share video through this approach?
2. If not, please let me know if there is any possible way for this.

N.B. : I have already bothered the Google a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solutions ?

Comment: No not yet, but I do have found some more information about this topic. Currently not working on it. But hopefully I will be back on this real soon. Also thinking about posting my findings here. Thank you for asking. 

Do you have any lead about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

my problem was passing a bad filePath, so i found a solution like below :

```
import {CaptureError, MediaFile, MediaCapture, CaptureImageOptions, Transfer} from "ionic-native";`

declare let cordova: any;

 private static options = {
    message: '', // not supported on some apps (Facebook, Instagram)
    subject: '', // for email
    files: [''], // an array of filenames either locally or remotely
    url: ''
  };

videoOptions: CaptureImageOptions = {limit: 1};
videoData: any;

captureVideo() {
    MediaCapture.captureVideo(this.videoOptions)
      .then(
        (data: MediaFile[]) => {
          this.videoData = data[0];
          const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
          fileTransfer.download(this.videoData.fullPath, cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'fileDir/filename.mp4').then((entry) => {

             this.options.message = " Your message";
             this.options.subject = "Your Subject";
             this.options.files = [entry.toURL()];
             this.options.url = "https://www.google.com.tr/";

             SocialSharing.shareWithOptions(this.options);

          }, (error) => {
          });
        },
        (err: CaptureError) => {
        }
      );
  }
```

As you see above, i just copy my video file to **applicationStorageDirectory**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it and inform you. :)